# Facebook SDK error loading on Windows 10 app (XAML, C#)

Tags: c#, facebook, visual-studio, winrt-xaml

This is very odd, yesterday this project loaded fine and today it doesn't want to.

Here is the error message:

C:\Dailymotion\dailymotion-windows-universal\Libs\winsdkfb-master\FBWinSDK\FBSDK-UWP\FBSDK-UWP\FBSDK-UWP.vcxproj : error  : The method or operation is not implemented.

Project 'Facebook' could not be loaded because it's missing install components. To fix this launch Visual Studio setup with the following selections:
Install Universal Windows Platform Tools

C:\Dailymotion\dailymotion-windows-universal\Libs\winsdkfb-master\FBWinSDK\FBSDK-UWP\FBSDK-UWP\FBSDK-UWP.vcxproj : error  : The method or operation is not implemented.

What is crazy is that i already have "Install Universal Windows Platform Tools" installed because i am developing a Windows 10 app! anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you upgrade your UWP tools?
I'm using VS 2015 Update 1 with UWP Tools 1.2 and I'm able to build https://github.com/Microsoft/winsdkfb/tree/master/FBWinSDK/FBSDK-UWP without errors.

Comment: You're welcome Damien. Make us the best Dailymotion app ever ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reporting this issue with using Visual Studio 2015 RTM to open C++ UWP apps, and our apologies for introducing this error.

We've released a fix for this issue. While we encourage you to install Update 1, you *do not* need to do so to get this fix. VS will automatically download the fix

1. If you have an internet connection, and
2. Once every 24 hours upon restarting Visual Studio.

So, if you wait until 24 hours from now, you’ll get the fix. If you want to force it sooner, here’s instructions:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Open %appdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\FeedCache
3. Copy all the files out to a new folder
4. Make sure you have in internet connection and restart Visual Studio
5. Wait a few minutes and you’ll see a new file appear in the FeedCache folder
6. You can copy the old files back into the folder if you want

If you can’t successfully open your project with a pre-Update 1 Visual Studio, please let us know.

Thanks!
-Paul Chapman
Visual Studio PM